# Maximum area without use of derivative

Tags: derivatives

In a [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692869/show-that-the-maximum-area-of-a-rectangle-inscribed-in-a-circle-sector-of-angle) here, the area of an inscribed yellow rectangle is shown maximum when OB bisects the central sector angle POQ using differentiation.

Is it possible to arrive at this result without finding derivative by logic of increasing and decreasing functions ( base/height of the rectangle) ?

[image]

Comment: One thing to note is that the area is symmetric about $\theta/2$ so if you can argue that the area is increasing on $(0,\theta/2)$, it must be a global max.

Comment: @Narsimham I have a solution via trigonometric manipulation. Please wait for my answer before accepting any.

Comment: No problem, plenty of time for answers,comments and discussions.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

According to the figure, $BC=\sin\alpha$ and $DC=\cos\alpha-\frac{\sin\alpha}{\tan\theta}$.

Let $\tan\theta=a$. Now the area is
$$A=\sin\alpha\cos\alpha-\frac{\sin^2 \alpha}{a}$$
$$=\frac{a\sin2\alpha +\cos 2\alpha -1}{2a}$$
To maximize area, it is sufficient to maximize $a\sin2\alpha +\cos 2\alpha$. This can be done by writing it as
$$\sqrt{a^2+1}\left(\dfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\sin 2\alpha+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\cos 2\alpha\right)$$

Now substitute $a=\tan\theta$ and you obtain
$$A=\frac{sec\theta\cos(\theta-2\alpha)-1}{2\tan\theta}$$

For maximum, $\theta=2\alpha$ and we are done!